# Python how to check if value changed

Tags: python

I want to print "Same number" if the new number value equals to the last one(same number), else print number variable value if it has changed. How can I do that?

```
from random import randint
x=0
number=(randint(0,9))
while(x<10):
    x+= 1
    if(number=="""LAST PRINTED VALUE NUMBER"""):
        print ("Same number")
    else:
        print(number)
```

Comment: Keep track of the previous number?

Comment: Also, you need to update `number` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chage last number in the while loop:

```
x, last = 0, -1
while (x < 10):
    number = randint(0, 9)
    if (number == last):
        print ("Same number")
    else:
        print("Last number is {0} now it is {1}".format(last,number))
    last = number
    x += 1
```

Output:

```
Last number is -1 now it is 1
Last number is 1 now it is 2
Last number is 2 now it is 4
Same number
Last number is 4 now it is 2
Last number is 2 now it is 6
Last number is 6 now it is 7
Same number
Last number is 7 now it is 2
Same number
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save the last one:

```
from random import randint
x=0
old = number= randint(0,9)
while(x<10):
    x+= 1
    if(number==old and x > 0):
        print ("Same number")
    else:
        print(number)
    old = number
    number = randint(0,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
x = 0
number = -1
while(x < 10):
    y = number
    number=(randint(0,9))
    x+= 1
    if(number== y):
        print ("Same number")
    else:
        print(number)
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a third variable.  Within the "else" after the print statement, set this third variable to "number".

Comment: Posting a brief code snippet along with your answer would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have a different method:

```
from random import randint
new = randint(0, 10)
old = new
for i in range(10):
    new = randint(0, 10)
    if new == old:
        print("Same number  ({0})".format(new))
    else:
        print("Diffrent     (Last: {0} Now: {1})".format(old, new))
        old = new
```

Output:

```
Diffrent     (Last: 6 Now: 9)
Diffrent     (Last: 9 Now: 0)
Diffrent     (Last: 0 Now: 2)
Same number  (2)
Diffrent     (Last: 2 Now: 6)
Same number  (6)
Diffrent     (Last: 6 Now: 7)
Diffrent     (Last: 7 Now: 4)
Same number  (4)
Diffrent     (Last: 4 Now: 10)
```